# Design of CBVs in Django

Tags: python, django

I'm currently trying to get into "Class Based Views" with Django 1.5.

From the design perspective i wonder where to put the logic to process data comming from a form **in a simple FormView**.

I know that all form validation code comes into the method `form_valid()`. But where to put things which processes data of the form. I read that its somehow inappropriate to put too much logic into the `form_valid()` method.

There are the `get()`, `post()`, `get_context_data()`, `head()`, etc. methods... which should I use in which case?

Comment: Have you read https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/class-based-views/generic-editing/ ?

Comment: jep! But that was not very helpful to me!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Form validation, data cleaning, etc goes with the form class in the clean methods
2. Processing of a valid form should go in an overridden `form_valid` method

That's it! If your use-case is more complicated you can call out to other methods of your creation from `form_valid`...

Answer (score 1):

Any answer to this question is open for discussion. That said, views are just Python classes, so you *could* overwrite any method to customize things accordingly.

It is also perfectly legit to create an extra method on your class to handle data processing.